# In Unity3D, update is called on every script all at once. How?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How is that accomplished, and could I use the system type myself? Is it abstracts?

Comment: What makes you think that it calls all of them at once? (It's not true)

Comment: Okay, not litteraly. I meant automatically. How does Unity _know_ to call the method on all the monobehaviours in the scene?

Comment: For the exact implementation details you'd have to ask the Unity3D developers. But in essence all Scripts that get attached via the Inspector get registered in a list which is then iterated every frame.

Comment: For one script, the order is like https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html. For all the script, it really depends. But you could set the order in Editor->Project Setting->Script Execution Order

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think you can use the Start function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the exact code for that is called by unity itself and you cant view it with applications like ILSpy.

Essentially though, Unity takes all GameObjects in the active scene and checks their MonoBehaviour script for an update function and if they do, it invokes it.

You could imagine it similar to something like this:

```
void OnFrameRender ()
{
    foreach (GameObject g in allGameObjectsInCurrentScene)
    {
        MonoBehaviour m = g.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
        if (m.GetType().GetMethod("Update") != null)
            m.Invoke("Update");
    }
    // Additional render logic
}
```

Since Unity itself is coded in C++ and not in C# this is not going to be the exact code but the approach could be similar.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had meant!